# Nexus 7 rooting and battery life

Tags: nexus-7, battery-life

I rooted my new nexus 7 the other day using the Nexus Root Toolkit.

Before rooting I was able to get about a full day out of a charge and still be at about 20-30% but now my battery seems to drain faster and even drain while I have the screen locked.

Can root affect battery life? Or could it be an application?

Comment: What did you root for? Presumably you rooted your phone to accomplish something that couldn't be done without root access? What have you used your root access for? What root-only apps have you installed, what system settings have you changed? There are lots of things you can do once you have root access, some of these will affect your battery life, some won't. It would be make this easier to answer if we knew what else you've done.

Comment: I've flashed Cyanogen and ive used root for. Ore advanced features in  Tasker. I also replaced my boot animation and changed soft keys

Answer (score 1):

Rooting the Nexus 7 means that just some additional applications are installed, e.g. the su binary and the SuperSU app.

Both are not active in background, therefore I assume that your battery life problem is caused by a different app that had been updated or installed more or less at the same time.

Comment: I'll have to look as soon as I'm off work. Thanks